# Kendo Scheduler week view collapse hours

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler

My goal is to group the Scheduler by user (vertical orientation) so that each row represents a user and each cell represents a full day per user (instead of multiple cells for each hour)

I could find how to customize the hours displayed but I couldn't find how to replace them with just one cell representing the whole day. The "all-day" row is not suitable since it only shows the events that occupy the whole workday